# DevExpress XtraEditors TextEdit mask to completely replace exact string?

Tags: regex, devexpress

I have an exact string which is retrieved from a database. For sake of argument, lets use this as an example:

```
string dataText = "set of characters";
```

I need to be able to replace that text with some other text, also retrieved from a database using the mask. For sake of argument, lets use this replacement text as an example.

```
string replacementText = "this string is private!";
```

I need to complete this line, but I can't figure out the regex I would need to use to force the mask to replace the dataText with replacementText

```
textEditSomething.Properties.Mask.EditMask = ???
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You sure that you need regex? Maybe you are looking for System.Windows.Forms.Binding.Format event? Please show some real examples for `dataText` and `replacmentText`